# Midlet-browser interaction

Tags: java, browser, java-me, mobile, midlet

Is there anyway to interact between a phone's browser and a midlet?
As far as I understand it they both run in different sand box and except if using platform specific api communication between midlet and native apps is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is no cross-platform API for interacting with the browser on the device. On Nokia Symbian devices you can use the [eSWT Browser](http://goo.gl/2AkDv) widget to embed the platform's browser inside the midlet and have some limited interaction with it through the eSWT Browser APIs.